# MASM automatic insertion of segment initialization code in 16-bit code

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

I am writing assembly language program 16 bit in dosbox using masm611. I compile and link it using

```
masm a.asm  
link a.obj
```

then i start debugging using  `cv a`

but in the code shown in the cv it inserts the following code automatically

```
    mov     ax,@data
    mov     ds,ax
    mov     bx,ss
    sub     bx,ax
    shl     bx,4
    mov     ss,ax
    add     sp,bx
```

the above code is inserted automatically. Does anyone knows what this code is doing and why it is inserted.

The a.asm file contains the following code:

```
.model small  
.stack 4096  
.data  
hello_message   db  'Hello World!', 0dh, 0ah, '$'  
.code  
 .startup   ;  
    mov ax,@data  
    mov ds,ax  
    mov ah,9  
    mov dx,offset hello_message  
    int 21h  
    mov ax,4C00h  
    int 21h  
.exit  
end
```

Comment: What it is doing is effectively setting the Stack segment to the same 64kb segment as _DS_ and then adjusts _SP_ accordingly.

Comment: It is possible that the `.startup` macro generated that section of code, which would make sense since it is probably trying to insure that DS=SS for the [small memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model)

Comment: `mov ax,@data` is used to get the segment of the data section in your code. But that segment won't be known until runtime. The linker won't know exactly where the data segment is when DOS loads it so it places a segment fixup entry in the DOS header of the program. That gets competed (resolved) by DOS before control is transferred to your program.

Comment: If using `.startup` you can remove the `mov ax,@data` `mov ds,ax` that you placed below it since `.startup` macro will do that for you.

Comment: `.exit` should also generate instructions that would also be added to your program to terminate.

Comment: You may wish to read the MASM 6.1 manual which is available here: http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf . It discusses `.startup`, `.exit` and segmentation + memory models.

Comment: Hmm... the code that `.startup` inserts is less than optimal. It could be simplified to `mov ax,@data` `mov ds,ax` `mov ss,ax` `mov sp,OFFSET DGROUP:STACK`

Comment: I have still one question that i was not able to understand that why it is shifting by 4 (multiplying by 16) to adjust the pointer. Although, I understood that it adjusts the stack pointer a bit more than the combined size of the stack and data segment. So, when i debug it basically what it does that it makes the starting address of the stack segment and data segment in such a way when the difference of the two addresses is shifted by 4 the stack pointer moves to the distance of  abit more than the combined size of declared data in the data segment and stack size